# Snowflake time travel

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would need to create tables with use of snowflake time travel but not to drop tables and create new objects. I'm looking for most efficient way to do that.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE_SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME AS SELECT * FROM TABLE_SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME at(timestamp => '2020-11-01 07:00:00'::timestamp);
```

In snowflake documentation I found out that by running a CREATE OR REPLACE, the original table is dropped and replaced with a new table. There will be no time-travel data from before the replace table was issued. If I need to remove the data from a table and retain the data for time-travel purposes, I can use TRUNCATE TABLE statement. My question is shoud I use TRUNCATE or CREATE OR REPLACE? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach is [INSERT OVERWIRTE INTO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html):

```
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO TABLE_SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME 
AS 
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME at(timestamp => '2020-11-01 07:00:00'::timestamp);
```

---

> I would also like to know how overite effects time travel...historical data?

It is still possible to access data before INSERT OVERWRITE as long as it is within data retention period.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TAB(id INT) AS SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2;

-- original table
SELECT * FROM TAB;
-- 1
-- 2

UPDATE TAB SET id = id * 10;
SET queryupdate = LAST_QUERY_ID();

-- after update
SELECT * FROM TAB;
-- 10
-- 20

-- restoring state before update
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO TAB SELECT * FROM TAB BEFORE(STATEMENT => $queryupdate);
SET queryinsertoverwrite = LAST_QUERY_ID();

-- current state
SELECT * FROM TAB;
-- 1
-- 2

-- state before update
SELECT * FROM TAB BEFORE(STATEMENT => $queryupdate);
-- 1
-- 2

-- state before insert overwrite
SELECT * FROM TAB BEFORE(STATEMENT => $queryinsertoverwrite);
-- 10
-- 20
```

Comment: @LukaszSzkoda but for big tables insert will take a long time. I would also like to know how overite effects time travel...historical data?