# Migrating Time Travel history when Cloning an object with Time Travel

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When restoring an object using `CLONE ... AT` and then `ALTER ... SWAP WITH`, we can very quickly restore a problematic table/database.

```sql
    CREATE TABLE my_table_restore CLONE my_table AT(OFFSET => -3600);
    ALTER TABLE my_table SWAP WITH my_table_restore;
    DROP TABLE my_table_restore;
```

But this approach treats the cloned table as new, and means the new 'production' table now has no further Time Travel permitted. This could be problematic if we discover a further issue that requires an older restore.

We've identified two possible mitigations, but neither are great;

1. Restore the dropped `_restore` table and grab an earlier snapshot from there

```sql
UNDROP TABLE my_table_restore
```

But this feels 'clunky' at best.

2. Use in-place restores as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73866961/2123163) using `INSERT OVERWRITE`
   But this is slower, and reduces the ability to a/b test the result (could clone first, then perform an `INSERT OVERWRITE` of course)

Is there an option 3), which allows the time travel to remain with the original table rather than being lost/reset?

Comment: Why drop the original table if there is still a potentially need for it? Leave it as it is and create a new clone from it at a different time point